# Inserting data from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I've got two tables where I'm trying  to insert data from one to another, I've been able to find a few examples of how this can be accomplished on the web, the problem is these examples mostly rely on identical table structure between the two ... you see I'm trying to insert *some* data from one table into another table with quite a different structure.

I'm trying to insert data from a table called 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' into a table called 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'. Below is a simple description of their structure

The 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' looks as follows:

```
value_id  |   entity_type_id  |  attribute_id  |  store_id     |  entity_id  |   value
     PK              INT              INT            INT              INT       VARCHAR
```

And the 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' table looks as follows:

```
value_id   |   attribute_id    |    entity_id    |    value
    PK               INT                INT          VARCHAR
```

I need to insert the entity, and value columns from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery into catalog_product_entity_varchar. However as you can see the structure is quite different.

The query I'm trying to use is as follows

```
USE magento_db;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar(entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)

SELECT
 4,
 74,
 0,
 catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id,
 catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value

FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;
```

I only need the entity_id and value from media_gallery and the other values are always the same, I have tried to do this using the above but this is just hanging in MySQL (no errors)

I think it's due to the fact that I'm trying to select 4, 74 and 0 from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery but I'm not 100% sure (apologies, I'm a bit of a novice with MySQL)

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Is there any way way I can insert some data from the media table whilst inserting static values for some columns? (I hope this all makes sense)

Comment: How many rows does your select return? While your query is running, you can open another mysql command prompt and run 'show processlist' to see what mysql is doing. YOu can also do 'explain' to see if you need an index to speed this up. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish from an application level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query syntax is ok.

However, there may be issues with the unique and foreign keys in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table, which doesn't allow you to insert data. Also the query may be waiting for some other query to complete (if your query is just a part of bigger scenario), so it is an issue with locking. Most probable is the first case.

Currently, the question lacks important details:

- The MySQL client / programming code you use to perform query. So we
  are not able to see the case in full and to reproduce it correctly
- The scenario you perform. I.e. whether you do it inside the Magento application in some
  module during a web-request. Or whether there are other queries in your script, 
  some opened transactions, other people accessing the DB server, etc.

Based on most probable assumption that you just don't see the actual error with unique/foreign keys, you may try the following queries.

1) Unique index failure. 
Try this:

```
USE magento_db;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar(entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)

SELECT
    4 as etid,
    74 as aid,
    0 as sid,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id as eid,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value as val
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
GROUP BY 
    eid, aid, sid;
```

There is a huge possibility, that you insert non-unique entries, because `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` can hold multiple entries for the same product, while `catalog_product_entity_varchar` can not. If the query above successfully completes, then the issue is really with unique key. In such a case you must re-verify what you want to achieve, because the initial aim (not the query itself) is wrong.

2) Wrong foreign key (non-existing attribute 74)

Try this (replacing ATTRIBUTE_CODE and ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID with the values you need, e.g. 'firstname' and 6):

```
USE magento_db;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar(entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT
    4 as etid,
    eav_attribute.attribute_id as aid,
    0 as sid,
    gallery.entity_id as eid,
    gallery.value as val
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS gallery
INNER JOIN
    eav_attribute
    ON
        eav_attribute.attribute_code = '<ATTRIBUTE_CODE>'
        AND eav_attribute.entity_type_id = <ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID>
GROUP BY 
    eid, aid, sid;
```

If it executes successfully AND

- Some rows are added to the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` - then it seems, that 74 was chosen as a wrong id of the attribute you needed, thus foreign key in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` didn't allow you to insert the records.
- No rows are added to the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` - then it seems, that you mistake in attribute id, attribute code and entity type. Recheck, what you put as ATTRIBUTE_CODE and ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID.

If both queries still hang - then you have issues with your MySQL client or server or execution scenario.

**Note**: your initial query may make sense in your specific case, but some issues are signalling that something may be wrong with your approach, because:

1. You're using direct numbers for ids. But ids are different for different installations and Magento versions. It is expected to use more stable values, like attribute code in second query, by which you should extract the actual attribute id.
2. You copy data from the storage `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`, which can store multiple entries for the same product, to the storage `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, which is able to store only one entry for the product. It means, that you cannot copy all the data in such a way. Probably, your query doesn't reflect the goal you want to achieve.
3. The entity type id, inserted to the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` is not related to attribute id. While in Magento these are deeply connected things. Putting the wrong entity type id in a table will either make Magento behave incorrectly, or it won't notice your changes at all.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thorough answer, shortly before you posted this I ended up restoring the database from another version of the site I was running, apparently that fixed it.

Comment: Regardless I'm marking it as correct because it taught me a lot and I feel bad for not adding enough detail in my original question! Some of the things you pointed out were indeed things I should have noticed. Again thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar( entity_id, value)
  VALUES (
          SELECT  entity_id, value
          FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery

           WHERE value_id = here the row id of value_id which have those values 4,74,0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `valued_id` in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table is an `autoincrement`, could you not do the following?

```
USE magento_db;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar(entity_type_id, store_id, entity_id, value)

SELECT
 4,
 74,
 catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id,
 catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value

FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;
```

Note that there is no `attribute_id` column in your `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a mistake in my question (now editied) valued_id is autoincrement but attribute_id is not and needs to be inserted.

Comment: No worries, @SeanDunwoody, I should really have just added my 'answer' as a comment.